# Get progress in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio (in python 3.6) to schedule multiple asynchronous tasks.

On the following example:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
import asyncio

def long_task(t):
    print(t)
    time.sleep(1)
    return t

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
futures = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, long_task, i) for i in inputs]
```

Is there a way to get the number of finished tasks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something, asyncio Future object have a done() function:

```py
from asyncio import Future
from typing import List

def get_progress(futures: List[Future]) -> int:
    return sum([f.done() for f in futures])
```